# How do I use UUID?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I use PhoneGap in Devextreme. I try Get UUID. But it isn't working and get an error. How do I use it? Why do I get an error?

> error

"onDeviceReady isn't defined"

> Add following to config.xml:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid" source="npm" />
```

> Add following to index.js:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
try {
 var uuid = device.uuid;
    alert(uuid);
 } catch (e) {
  alert(e);
        }
}
```

Comment: can u please elaborate the error u got ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that you are using `cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid` package to get uuid. 
This is how `cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid` library documentation tells to get device uuid.

```
// Get UUID
function onDeviceReady() {
  window.plugins.uniqueDeviceID.get(success, fail);
}


function success(uuid){
    console.log(uuid);
};

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
      try {
        var uuid = device.uuid;
            alert(uuid);
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
        }
 },true);
```

Comment: Hi, I was added. but the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the device plugin to your app just run

```
cordova plugin add --save cordova-plugin-device
```

then use the following code to get the device uuid.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
   alert(device.uuid);
}
```